# Struct inheritance

Tags: rust

A typical AST implementation in C might look like:

```c
typedef enum {
    AST_IDENT,
    AST_STRING,
} Ast_Tag;

typedef struct { Ast_Tag tag; u32 flags; } Ast;
typedef struct { Ast base; Intern *name; } Ast_Ident; 
typedef struct { Ast base; Intern *str;  } Ast_String;

// A function that downcasts to the derived type:
void foo (Ast *node) {
    switch (node->tag) {
    case AST_IDENT: {
        Ast_Ident *ident = (Ast_Ident*)node;
        do_something_with_name(ident->name);
    } break;

    case AST_STRING: {
        Ast_String *str = (Ast_String*)node;
        do_something_with_name(str->name);
    } break;
    }
}

// A function that upcasts to the base type:
void bar (Ast_Ident *ident) {
    foo((Ast*)ident);
}
```

Is there a way to do this in rust? I'd imagine that downcasting would be particularly problematic.

NOTE: I'm not asking how to implement an AST, but how to replicate the struct inheritance as demonstrated above.

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. The point here is that struct inheritance is used in order to avoid making every node be the same size, so enums are not an option.

Comment: That's what [`enum`s](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-00-enums.html) are for. Note that `enum`s in Rust are quite a different beast from C/C++ `enum`s.

Comment: @Jmb Enums cannot replicate the above code. An enum causes all nodes to be the same size.

Comment: From the code you posted I don't quite see why that would be a problem.

Comment: @Lagerbaer The point is that you want each node to only be as big as it needs to be.

Comment: Fair enough; but you didn't indicate in your question that you wanted to optimize for memory. _Conceptually_, enums are exactly for what you describe. A different question then if there are tricks to get enum elements in Rust to be optimized.

Comment: The title is struct inheritance in rust. I'm asking whether you can have the kind of struct inheritance as demonstrated in the code. Sorry if it wasn't obvious. I'll edit the question a bit.

Comment: No, there is no struct inheritance in rust. It uses other techniques, such as enums and traits. There are also Boxes and smart pointers to handle structs of unknown size.

Comment: "The point is that you want each node to only be as big as it needs to be" you didn't really demonstrate this point, true if you use allocation this would be true, but the same could be achieve with rust boxing, but it has been demonstrate that enum are almost always preferred, the only case would be VERY big diff in enum size variant, clippy have a lint for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference multiple types as a trait, but you can't cast the trait object to the exact type. To the rescue is the [Any](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/index.html) trait, which has a `is`, `downcast_ref`, and `Box<dyn Any>` has a `downcast` method. You can also get type IDs.

But there is no inheritance like you see in many OOP languages. That goal is accomplished by implementing traits.

Comment: Ah, it seems Any is what I was looking for.

Comment: @zagortenay333: You'll probably be unable to use `Any` in this case, because its methods are only available on `'static` types whereas your `Intern` members almost certainly have some other lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

You basically implement Rust `enum` variant:

```rust
struct Ast {
    flags: u32,
    kind: AstKind,
}

enum AstKind {
    Ident(String),
    String(String),
}

fn foo(ast: Ast) {
    match ast.kind {
        AstKind::Ident(ident) => println!("flags: {:?}, ident: {:?}", ast.flags, ident),
        AstKind::String(s) => println!("string: {:?}, ident: {:?}", ast.flags, s),
    }
}

fn bar(flags: u32, ident: String) {
    foo(Ast {
        flags,
        kind: AstKind::Ident(ident),
    })
}

fn main() {
    bar(42, "MisterMV".into())
}
```

You seem to be concern with the size:

> The point here is that struct inheritance is used in order to avoid making every node be the same size, so enums are not an option.

That generally not a concern, clippy have a lint call [`large_enum_variant`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/stable/index.html#large_enum_variant), with a reasonable default that you can change. Clippy also propose a reasonable solution:

```rust
enum AstKind {
    Ident(Box<Big>),
    String(Small),
}
```

There are other alternatives that other answer already cover.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as already pointed out. This causes all nodes to be the same size.

Comment: @zagortenay333 as pointed out, this is not demonstrate or even mention in your question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I updated the question again.

Answer (score -2):

That's impossible in safe Rust. You can however do it with [`transmute`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/mem/fn.transmute.html), provided that your structs are all `repr(C)`:

```
pub enum AstTag {
    AstIdent,
    AstString,
}

#[repr(C)]
pub struct Ast { tag: AstTag, flags: u32, }
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AstIdent { base: Ast, name: String, }
#[repr(C)]
pub struct AstString { base: Ast, string: String, }

// A function that downcasts to the derived type:
pub fn foo (node: &Ast) {
    use std::mem::transmute;
    match node.tag {
        AstTag::AstIdent => {
            let ident: &AstIdent = unsafe { transmute (node) };
            println!("{}", ident.name);
        },
        AstTag::AstString => {
            let ident: &AstString = unsafe { transmute (node) };
            println!("{}", ident.string);
        }
    }
}

// A function that upcasts to the base type:
pub fn bar (ident: &AstIdent) {
    foo (&ident.base);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5f9f8e642c52525152bb95565d299a70)

However this is very unidiomatic. A much more idiomatic way of doing things would be to put `foo` in a trait and implement that trait for each struct:

```
pub struct AstIdent { flags: u32, name: String, }
pub struct AstString { flags: u32, string: String, }

pub trait Foo {
    fn foo (&self);
}

impl Foo for AstIdent {
    fn foo (&self) {
        println!("{}", self.name);
    }
}

impl Foo for AstString {
    fn foo (&self) {
        println!("{}", self.string);
    }
}

pub fn bar (ident: &AstIdent) {
    ident.foo();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ef5e38e55c644ea05eaa00f9e967b17)

Comment: @Stargateur, uhm, doesnt miri just complains about main function there?

Comment: @Stargateur With `repr(C)`, there shouldn't be any undefined behaviour here. Miri is only complaining about the missing `main` function.

Comment: [Miri report UB](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b36ad66724afbe77e32fe8b53b74b2d7)

Comment: @Frxstrem that makes it unsafe, but not unsound so long as you don't try to use it outside the original lifetime.